# how can i copy a value of a column and copy it to another column or measure?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

i have a column like this one, and i want to copy de last value, different of 0, in each row of the new column

| Col 1 | New Col |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 0 | 5 |
| 0 | 5 |
| 0 | 5 |

Comment: solution:
nueva columna =
var _max = maxX(filter(Table, [Sales] >0 && not(isblank([Sales]))),[Semana])
devolución
sumx(filter(Table, [Week] =_max),[Sales])